# Need to get all key value pairs from a JSON containing a specific character '/'

Tags: json, jq

I have a specific json content for which I need to get all keys which contains the character / in their values.

**JSON**

```
{ "dig":  "sha256:d2aae00e4bc6424d8a6ae7639d41cfff8c5aa56fc6f573e64552a62f35b6293e",
 "name": "example",
 "binding": { 
   "wf.example.input1": "/path/to/file1",
   "wf.example.input2": "hello",
   "wf.example.input3":
     ["/path/to/file3",
      "/path/to/file4"],
   "wf.example.input4": 44
  }
}
```

I know I can get all the keys containing file path or array of file paths using query `jq 'paths(type == "string" and contains("/"))'`. This would give me an output like:

```
[ "binding", "wf.example.input1" ]
[ "binding", "wf.example.input3", 0]
[ "binding", "wf.example.input3", 1 ]
```

Now that i have all the elements that contains some file paths as their values, is there a way to fetch both key and value for the same and then store them as another JSON? For example, in JSON mentioned for this question, I need to get the output as another JSON containing all the matched paths. My output JSON should look something like below.

```
 { "binding":
   { "wf.example.input1": "/path/to/file1",
     "wf.example.input3": [ "/path/to/file3", "/path/to/file4" ] 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following jq filter will produce the desired output if given input that is very similar to the example, but it is far from robust and glosses over some details that are unclear from the problem description. However, it should be easy enough to modify the filter in accordance with more precise specifications:

```
. as $in
| reduce paths(type == "string" and test("/")) as $path ({};
    ($in|getpath($path)) as $x
    | if ($path[-1]|type) == "string"
      then .[$path[-1]] = $x
      else .[$path[-2]|tostring] += [$x]
      end )
| {binding: .}
```

Output:

```
{
  "binding": {
    "wf.example.input1": "/path/to/file1",
    "wf.example.input3": [
      "/path/to/file3",
      "/path/to/file4"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is this command doing here?